# Google calendar api download Nuget Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, api, google-calendar-api, nuget-package

Hi I'm trying to download the Google Calendar v3 API from nuget. When I type "Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 -Pre" into the Package Manager console in Visual Studio 2010, I get this error:

```
PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 -Pre
Install-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Pre'.
At line:1 char:45
+ Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 -Pre <<<< 
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Install-Package], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Not Sure where I went wrong. I'm pretty sure that is exactly what they tell you to do on NuGet's website. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

could you please try with the latest NuGet from http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget? it does not repro for me.

also, which project type are you trying to install the package to?