# Where do I get Google Calendar API v3 .dll files (ASP.NET)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, google-calendar-api

I'm having difficulty downloading the Google Calendar API v3 libraries for ASP.NET (C#)? I am using visual studio 2010, and tried to access them via Nuget, but it did not work. I'm getting an error as stated in this question ([Google calendar api download Nuget Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220912/google-calendar-api-download-nuget-error)). Is there somewhere I can just download the dll files manually and get it working that way?

Thank you.

Comment: Install it from the NuGet Package Manager UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the dll s direct like this example  :
 http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-we-can-use-google-calendar-in-asp-net-through-google-ap/

and find the dll s in u machine and add it in project and Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you for the link, but that is either v1 or v2. I'm looking for v3.